# SSAS - errors in OLE DB and OLAP storage engine

Tags: sql, ssas

My analysis project gives following errors when I try to deploy. I tried every possible solutions given by people in the internet and found no luck. Even though I get these errors, related database is created in my server( My server is in a remote location and I have admin permission there too)

These main two errors are coming even though my connection is success with the server:

[image]

Please give me a possible solution to overcome this error.

Comment: The only error you need to worry about is `Login Timeout Expired`. Fix that and the rest will start working. The other errors are because of that. For starters try using TCP/IP instead of named pipes

Comment: But it is already set to 1 hour. My queries doesn't take more than 1 - 2 minutes to select all the data manually. What possible reason can gives the timeout error.

Comment: There's also `server not found or accessible`. Basically you have a database connectivity issue that you need to solve

Comment: Database is already connected and even my SSAS databases are created in server

Comment: You have two connectivity errors in your log but it doesn't seem like you want any help.

Comment: I simultaneously ran two projecrs   which are connected to two different servers. Once i closed one connection the other project deployed successfully.so I am confused what could be the real reason.

Comment: Have they ever deployed successfully in the past? can you test the database connections that are being used? can you go on to the SSAS server and confirm that you can connect to the source database (SQL Server?)

Comment: They weren't deployed successfully in the past. I test the connection which are being used and it works perfectly. my source database and the SSAS server is in same location(cloud). I can't think of any possible reason. I am quite new to SSAS too.

Comment: How did you test it? Did your test use named pipes?

Comment: I used named pipes. I changed it to tcp to check for any difference.but didnt find any.

Comment: So you have tested connectivity to your SQL Server from your SSAS server... somehow.... and you tried named pipes and TCP/IP and it worked. However when you deploy your cube to the SSAS server it fails with connectivity errors.

Comment: I didnt create cubs. I used existing data views and directly created data mining structures there. And yes deployment failed. Now it is working properly after I removed the other simultaneous connection. But I want to know the reason for deployment error earlier. Thanks

Comment: The reason is on the log `server not found or accessible` and `Login Timeout Expired` means it couldn't connect to the source database. I can't help any further unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

The reason for above error was, I have tried to deploy my model in remote server while accessing local data Source. Both sql versions were not same and after changing it to same version it worked. Also make sure you have enough permissions in remote server to access it via SSAS

Comment: I think you need to give @Nick.McDermaid a big thank you. I'm sure his patients and guidance lead you to find the underlying issue. And he was fundamentally right: the two connection errors were the root of your issue.

Comment: I agree. His guidance helped me to correct the error. Thank you @Nick.McDermaid

Answer (score -1):

You have processed all dimension one by one and then try to process, sometimes it gives you usual errors like above.

Comment: This is coming as a deployment error. It haven't started to process dimensions.

Comment: @MuthuMK, deploy cube without processing, and try to process dimensions one by one, to reproduce the error.

Comment: I didnt create any cube.this model was directly processed with existing data in database